# VS2019 runsettings is not excluding some files from code coverage results as I expect

Tags: c#, c++, code-coverage, mstest, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019. C++, C# and C++ CLI

I am successfully using a .runsettings to exclude several undesired items from the Code Coverage Results. However, nothing I have tried seems to work for excluding gcroot.h. Here's a screenshot of the Code Coverage Results window.

[image]

This is under:

mylib.tests.dll | Global Classes | (then the gcroot )

I have tried several regex to exclude the Source path and none of them get it. Even this one does not exclude it:

```
<Source>.*\\Program\sFiles.*\\.*</Source>
```

That should exclude everything with  "Program Files" in the path. The full path of the gcroot file is

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\msclr\gcroot.h"
```

I put that in regexr.com and it matches, yet I still get gcroot.h in my code cov.